# Can ceiling light mount box be used to attach ceiling fan?

Tags: light-fixture, ceiling-fan, mounting

As Montreal is going to welcome the humid summer, I am planning to install a ceiling fan by removing the ceiling light. I have selected the fan that I want from Amazon. Here are the photos of the ceiling light fixture and its mounting box. But I am not sure if it needs a fan mounting box ? or will this ceiling light mount box can be used for the fan too ?

[This is the fan](https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B00I5WUDT8/ref=ox_sc_act_title_1?smid=A3DWYIK6Y9EEQB&psc=1) that I am planning to buy.

[image]

Here is how my mount looks:

[image]

[image]

Comment: the question is what supports are holding your electrical box in place. That will determine if you can use it to mount your fan. Is it mounted to a rafter beam or any supporting structure..

Comment: @ken because I cannot access the ceiling from above, I will have to examine this box up close to check how its mounted. I will get back soon.

Comment: your box should also have a weight load stamped on it - for max weight it can hold. If not 35lbs is the max weight, IF you have the proper mounting in the ceiling for the box.

Comment: While you're checking the box you should determine if there is a ceiling joist up there. If the box is not sufficient there are fans that have a plate that screws to the joist so you don't need a fan rated box that is assuming you have a joist close enough. .

Comment: @PlatinumGoose I will check those up close this weekend and post my findings.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe.

If the box has a bracket that securely attaches it to a framing member, then the box can support a ceiling fan up to 35 lbs.  If the box is not securely attached to a framing member, it cannot support a ceiling fan. According to NEC, ceiling boxes are supposed to be installed so that they can support a 50 lbs fixture (that's a light fixture, not a ceiling fan). However, this is not always the case, especially where the boxes are installed by those unaware of the code requirements, or before it was a requirement.

If the box is designed for supporting a ceiling fan, it will be marked with the amount of weight it can support, up to 70 lbs.  A ceiling fan weighing more than 70 lbs., has to be supported by other means.

Answer (score -2):

Not usually, ceiling fans have a hollow threaded rod that is usually mounted through a 2X4 nailed across the bottom of your ceiling trusses or between the floor joists of an upper floor.

EDIT:

The fan electric junction box must be securely affixed to a structural part of the ceiling. Often this is done with wood or metal braces that are strung on or between ceiling joists. Many today have mounting hardware separate from the junction box where wiring connections are made. Ensure you find if the wires are rated for the electric current load of the fan and lights and it's a good idea to have the wiring inspected by a competent electrician.

http://extremehowto.com/ceiling-fan-installation/

https://www.google.com/search?q=ceiling+fan+mounting+box&hl=en&site=webhp&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiX1ZuYlvrTAhVHHGMKHZj_BgUQ_AUIBygC&biw=1661&bih=905#imgrc=_

SECOND EDIT:

Here is a link to the company website's [installation manual](http://www.hunterfan.com/SupportDocuments/OwnersManuals/M0043-01.pdf) for this fan. It states that you must have a 'fan rated' junction box or use the mounting hardware provided. It does appear to be a ball and socket style mount and from the pictures you provided I cannot see that you have a fan rated junction box. Find where the joists run and use the long screws provided to secure the mounting bracket into the wood joist.

Comment: The biggest problem with installing a ceiling fan is the weight that the box can support, which this answer does not even try to address. The ceiling fan will have hardware to mount to a box (hollow threaded rod or not), but the box must be able to support the force of a spinning fan.

Comment: The question was will the box work. The answer I provided was not usually, then I described what the mounting system often looks like. No need to be snarky.

Comment: It would be great if you can provide a picture of how a typical ceiling fan mounts, then

Comment: @Gwydionforge, I don't see where anyone was snarky. You're flat wrong about how fans are suspended, at least for the last 2-3 decades. Nearly all use a [ball socket that attaches to the junction box](https://www.lowes.com/projects/images/how-tos/Heating-Cooling/replace-a-ceiling-fan-inline-ball.jpg). If that box is securely mounted to framing it will probably work just fine.

Comment: "You're flat wrong" and "does not even try to address" are comments that do not bring any benefit to the conversation or the original questioner's problem. As I said above, the original question was "will this work" I answered "not usually" because secure mounting hardware is required. Ball and socket is one way to mount them, but there are many other methods and looks that designers and consumers desire that won't work with a ball and socket. Please follow my links in the answer and see for yourself.